# Openlayers 3 points got covered by polygons

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

```
var normalstyles = {
    'Point': [new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({ 
                color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)'
            }),
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ 
                color: 'rgba(0,0,0,1)'
            }),
            radius: 5
        })
    })],
    'Polygon': [new ol.style.Style({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            width: 1,
            color: 'rgba(255,255,0,0)'
        })
    })]
};

var geoJSON = new ol.layer.Image({
    title: 'buildings',
    source: new ol.source.ImageVector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
            url: 'data/geojson',
            format: new ol.format.GeoJSON({
                defaultDataProjection :'EPSG:4326', 
                projection: 'EPSG:3857'
            })
        }),
        style: function(feature, resolution){
            var geom = feature.getGeometry().getType();
            return normalstyles[geom];
        }      
    })
});

var highlightstyles = {
    'Point': [new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({ 
                color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.1)'
            }),
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ 
                color: '#f00'
            }),
            radius: 5
        })
    })],
    'Polygon': [new ol.style.Style({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.1)'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#f00',
            width: 1
        })
    })]
};

var map = new ol.Map({      
    layers: [new ol.layer.Tile({ source: new ol.source.OSM()}), geoJSON],
    target: document.getElementById('map'),
    view: new ol.View({
        center: center,
        zoom: 15
    })
});

var featureOverlay = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector(),
    map: map,
    style: function(feature, resolution){
        var geom = feature.getGeometry().getType();
        return highlightstyles[geom];
    }
}); 

var highlight;
var displayFeatureInfo = function(pixel) {

    var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature) {
      return feature;
    });

    if (feature !== highlight) {
        if (highlight) {
            featureOverlay.getSource().removeFeature(highlight);
        }
        if (feature) {
            featureOverlay.getSource().addFeature(feature);
        }
        highlight = feature;
    }

};
```

This is my code. It basically shows the information in the geojson and gives them a highlight on mouseover effect. 
[[This is what it looks like when it is idle]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQQhq.jpg)
[[This is what it looks like when I mouseover the polygon]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DCqX.jpg)

For points outside of the polygon, I can get the highlight effect when I mouseover the circle which represents the point. However, those points which are inside polygons can't be reached. They are covered by the polygons.

Any idea on how to get those circles representing points not covered by polygons?

Update:

Now I've changed my code to this and points are getting highlights. However, polygons can't display the highlights anymore. Any idea?

```
var displayFeatureInfo = function(pixel) {

    var featurePoint = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature) {
        if (feature.getGeometry().getType() != 'Point') return feature;
    });

    var featurePolygon = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature) {
        if (feature.getGeometry().getType() != 'Polygon') return feature;
    });

    if (featurePoint !== highlight) {
        if (highlight) {
            featureOverlay.getSource().removeFeature(highlight);
        }
        if (featurePoint) {
            featureOverlay.getSource().addFeature(featurePoint);
        }
        highlight = featurePoint;
    }

    if (featurePolygon !== highlight) {
        if (highlight) {
            featureOverlay.getSource().removeFeature(highlight);
        }
        if (featurePolygon) {
            featureOverlay.getSource().addFeature(featurePolygon);
        }
        highlight = featurePolygon;
    }

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I can think of is to put your features in different layers, one for points and another for polygons this way in your

```
var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature, layer) {
//here you can add a condition on layer
  return feature;
});
```

or if it is absolutely necessary to keep them in one layer you can check the geometry type

```
var featurePoint = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature) {
    if(feature.getGeometry().getType()!="Point"){
        return feature;
    }
});
var featurePolygon = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature) {
    if(feature.getGeometry().getType()!="Polygon"){
       return feature;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Your method works although not perfectly. I updated the question. Could you take a look?

Comment: nvm I figured it out. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Zoff sorry I couldn't see you rcomment earlier ( timezone difference )